# Python3 regular expression not working on script, but works on pythex.org

Tags: regex, utf-8, pattern-matching, python-3.5

I am writing a script in Python3 and I want to use regular expressions. I have some utf-8 encoded files used as configuration files for my main script.

I wish to change some lines on them (classic configuration changes).

My code ,still in poc condition, is this:

```
regex = re.compile('^SHOW_ALL\s[^:]')
with open('./config.txt', encoding='utf-8', mode='r+') as old_file:
    for line in old_file.read():
            if regex.match(line):
                print(line)
```

and the `config.txt` is this:

```
#Κάτι στα ελληνικά

SHOW_ALL OFF 15
PRINT ON
SHOW_VALUES O

COM 0
PRINTER_NAME samsung_not_a_real_name
CAMERA 33
```

I checked my regular expression at [pythex.org](https://pythex.org/?regex=%5ESHOW_ALL%5Cs%5B%5E%3A%5D&test_string=%23%20K%CE%AC%CF%84%CE%B9%20%CF%83%CF%84%CE%B1%20%CE%B5%CE%BB%CE%BB%CE%B7%CE%BD%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%AC%0ASHOW_ALL%20OFF%2015%0A%23%20PRINT%20ON%0A%23%20SHOW_VALUES%20O%0A%0A%23%20COM%200%0A%23%20PRINTER_NAME%20samsung_not_a_real_name%0A%23%20CAMERA%2033%0A&ignorecase=0&multiline=1&dotall=0&verbose=0) and it seems to work fine.

What could be going wrong?

*the link redirects to the exact regex and text I tried myself at regex.org

Comment: Remove `.read()`, use `for line in old_file:`

Comment: Why does that work?

Comment: Because it means "read file line by line"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace `old_file.read();` by `old_file.readLines();`

Comment: It worked. Can you explain why? I've been using .read  for a long time and always worked. What changes with readlines()?

Comment: `readLines()` returns a list that contains all the lines of the file whereas `read()` returns all the file text as a string.`for line in old_file.read():` loop over each char of the file.

Comment: Well, it makes sense.